Modify Kentico listing view
Is there a way to modify the listing screen in Kentico's tree view?
Basically, my requirements are as follows

1.Set the default 'Page type' for a specific page type (Not a global change, just for specific page types)
2.Remove 'Show all levels' tick box



I would try creating an extender for that UI page. Or, you can still customize the physical code file and adjust the UniGrid logic:
CMSModules/Content/CMSDesk/View/listing.aspx
which uses this control
~/CMSModules/Content/Controls/DocumentList.ascx which uses the UniGrid.

Check out Kentico Extensions (https://github.com/timferres/kenticoextensions). It allows modifying the CMS interface without having to modify Kentico standard code which can cause issues when applying Kentico hotfixes.
